# Custom UserRepository dependencies for IdentityServer4 not resolved

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4

I am trying to take one step past the tutorials for IdentityServer4 towards a system I can use.  I have a user database that was developed for IdS3 that I want to continue to use.  My goal is to integrate a SQL Server database for the UserStore with IdS4, but without using Entity Framework.  I want to use ADO.NET operations instead.  I would handle transient faults with a "ReliableSqlConnection" using [Polly](http://www.thepollyproject.org/) to manage retry logic.

In Startup I have a ConfigureService as:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  IEnumerable<Client> clients = Clients.Get();
  IEnumerable<IdentityResource> identityResources = Resources.GetIdentityResources();
  IEnumerable<ApiResource> apiResources = Resources.GetApiResources();
  services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(identityResources)
    .AddInMemoryApiResources(apiResources)
    .AddInMemoryClients(clients)
    .AddMyUserStore();
  services.AddMvc();
}
```

The interesting add to this method beyond the tutorial is .AddMyUserStore() added to the AddIdentityServer().  The rest of it hasn't moved from the tutorial for a custom user repository.  The AddMyUserStore extension is:

```
    public static IIdentityServerBuilder AddMyUserStore(this IIdentityServerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.AddReliableConnectionToDataStore();
        builder.Services.AddSingletond<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IProvideClaims, ClaimRepository>();
        builder.AddProfileService<MyProfileService>();
        builder.AddResourceOwnerValidator<MyPasswordValidator>();
        return builder;
    }
```

The interesting line here is builder.AddReliableConnectionToDataStore(), with code as:

```
    private static void AddReliableConnectionToDataStore(this IIdentityServerBuilder builder)
    {
        const string connectionString = "server=...;";
        DbProviderFactory factory = SqlClientFactory.Instance;
        const int retryCount = 3;
        const int waitBetweenRetriesInMilliseconds = 100;
        builder
            .Services
            .AddSingleton<IProvideDbConnections>(
                s => new ReliableDbConnector(
                    connectionString,
                    factory,
                    new DatabaseCommunicationRetryPolicy(
                        retryCount,
                        waitBetweenRetriesInMilliseconds,
                        new[]
                        {
                            20, 64, 233, 4060, 4221, 10053, 10054, 10060,
                            40143, 40197, 40501, 40613, 49918, 49919, 49920
                        })));
    }
```

Where:

```
public interface IProvideDbConnections
{
    IDbConnection Connection { get; }
}
```

and ReliableDbConnection implements that.  The c'tor for UserRepository looks like:

```
    public UserRepository(IProvideDbConnections connector)
    {
        Connector = connector;
    }
```

I expected that since I had a IProvideDBConnections in the DI that the UserRepository would resolve fine.  I fire up the project.  The front page appears.  If I click the link to https://localhost:44349/grants on the fron page the error is:

"An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'MyUserRepository.UserRepository' while attempting to activate   'IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.AccountController'."

What am I missing?

*UPDATE*
The Account Controller in the tutorial is:

```
    public AccountController(
        IIdentityServerInteractionService interaction,
        IClientStore clientStore,
        IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemeProvider,
        IEventService events,
        UserRepository users)
    {
        Users = users;
        _interaction = interaction;
        _clientStore = clientStore;
        _schemeProvider = schemeProvider;
        _events = events;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to inject the concrete type `UserRepository` into your controller rather than the interface (`IUserRepository`) you registered?

Also, I'm not sure registering services that deal with database connections as singletons is a good idea, stick to transient or request scoped unless you have a strong reason not to.

Comment: I agree that lifetime should not be singleton, in the end.  This doesn't affect the resolution problem I have, does it?

Comment: Yes, the Account controller is taking a UserRepository, not a IUserRepository.  That's the part I missed.  Thank you.